# Python SCript - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'vertices'

Tags: python, scripting, vertices

I have several pieces of geometry, seemingly imported from some parametric modelling tool. They all have an ".ipt" in their object name.
My original goal was to write a script that goes through all the objects in the scene, gets the object's dimensions, counts the number of vertices in a an object, compares it to the same parameters in the active object, and replaces object data if it finds a match. To that end I wrote the following:

```
from bpy import context

scene = bpy.context.scene

actob = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
actobdat = bpy.context.selected_objects[0].data
ob = bpy.context.object
dimact = actob.dimensions
conapp = 0.007
actobvert = len(actobdat.vertices)

for ob in scene.objects:

    dimob = ob.dimensions
    obvert = len(ob.data.vertices)

    if abs(dimact[1] - dimob[1]) < conapp and abs(dimact[2] - dimob[2]) < conapp and abs(dimact[0] - dimob[0]) < conapp and actobvert == obvert:

        ob.select = True
        ob.data = actobdat
```

In response to this I received the following error message:
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'vertices'**

I did some searching online, but still failed to solve the issue.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What objects do you have in your scene? And are you using actob = bpy.context.selected_objects[0] to get the active object?

Comment: I have several identical (but not instance) meshes, that were imported from some parametrical modelling tool. The whole thing is a test for an ocasion when I will need to dig through a very large number of meshes, discern, which of them can use the same mesh data and apply said data to them.
To answer your second point - yes, this is why I have this line here. Is that a wrong\inefficient method of doing so?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It says 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'vertices', so it can be an empty that is being selected. You must check that the objects are meshes:

```
actob = bpy.context.active_object
if actob.type == 'MESH':
    actobdat = actob.data
    dimact = actob.dimensions
    [...]
    for ob in scene.objects:
        if ob.type == 'MESH':
            dimob = ob.dimensions
            etc...
```

You use bpy.context.active_object to get the active object, the index 0 of selected_objects will give you the last object added to the scene within the selection.

Comment: I would flip that condition, and do `if actop.type ! = 'MESH': continue`. That prevents yet another level of indentation.